# Read log file in R so that each row starts with timestamp

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a log file with such data inside:

```
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 10 - Trying to upload data
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 66 - Trying to upload data
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidationXmlParser: 127 - No META-Only annotation
2020-07-28 14:48:00 (pool-2-thread-1id) DEBUG MessageWriter: 55 - Send message ErrorOutputMessage(super=NotificationOutputMessage(super=OutputMessage(type=null, messageId=116345, reqId=af24112))), error=ErrorOutputMessage.Error(code=400, text={
  "errors": [
    "Message type error"
  ]
})) to exchange FOS 
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidatorFactoryImpl: 578 - Scoped message interpolator.
```

I try to read that file in this way:

```
data <- readr::read_lines(file = "log_data.log", progress = FALSE)
log_df <- setDT(tibble::enframe(data, name = NULL))
```

But this dataframe looks like this:

```
              value
1   2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 10 - Trying to upload data
 
2   2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 66 - Trying to upload data
3   2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidationXmlParser: 127 - No META-Only annotation
4   2020-07-28 14:48:00 (pool-2-thread-1id) DEBUG MessageWriter: 55 - Send message ErrorOutputMessage(super=NotificationOutputMessage(super=OutputMessage(type=null, messageId=116345, reqId=af24112))), error=ErrorOutputMessage.Error(code=400, text={
5     "errors": [
6         "Message type error"
7     ]
8   })) to exchange FOS 
9   2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidatorFactoryImpl: 578 - Scoped message interpolator.
```

So as you see row number 4 splited into several rows, thought  its one. How could i read this log file, so it understands that each row must start with timestamp? Should i use regular expressions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove all new-lines not followed by a date:

```
log_string <- '2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 10 - Trying to upload data
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 66 - Trying to upload data
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidationXmlParser: 127 - No META-Only annotation
2020-07-28 14:48:00 (pool-2-thread-1id) DEBUG MessageWriter: 55 - Send message ErrorOutputMessage(super=NotificationOutputMessage(super=OutputMessage(type=null, messageId=116345, reqId=af24112))), error=ErrorOutputMessage.Error(code=400, text={
  "errors": [
    "Message type error"
  ]
})) to exchange FOS 
2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidatorFactoryImpl: 578 - Scoped message interpolator.'

readr::read_lines(
    stringr::str_replace_all(
        log_string,
    
        # Regular expression
        '(\\r?\\n|\\r)(?!\\d{4}-(\\d{2}[-: ]){5})', '')
)
```

```
[1] "2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 10 - Trying to upload data"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[2] "2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper: 66 - Trying to upload data"                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[3] "2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidationXmlParser: 127 - No META-Only annotation"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[4] "2020-07-28 14:48:00 (pool-2-thread-1id) DEBUG MessageWriter: 55 - Send message ErrorOutputMessage(super=NotificationOutputMessage(super=OutputMessage(type=null, messageId=116345, reqId=af24112))), error=ErrorOutputMessage.Error(code=400, text={  \"errors\": [    \"Message type error\"  ]})) to exchange FOS "
[5] "2020-07-28 10:07:01 (pool-3-thread-5id) DEBUG ValidatorFactoryImpl: 578 - Scoped message interpolator."
```

`(\\r?\\n|\\r)` matches different versions of new-line.

`(?!\\d{4}-(\\d{2}[-: ]){5})` is a negative lookahead that matches a datetime (copied from EvilSmurf's answer).

Comment: I don't know R so I think you managed to finish it (also I wasn't reading properly, that french_fries wanted to exclude any extra lines not starting with a timestamp) - still don't get why someone is downvoting our answers

Comment: I have "set you back" to 0 ;)

Comment: Ditto. There may be a more elegant way to solve this, by as I see it, you have either remove the extra new-lines (as demonstrated here) or just disregard the newlines and split the string by the presence of a date-time (risky if date-times are used within messages).

Answer (score 0):

A two pass approach is possible:

1. In Notepad++, use regex replace with the `\R++(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )` pattern and some placeholder replacement, say, `<L1nBre@k>`. [Start the regex engine](https://regex101.com/r/EptHXE/1) to see how this expression works.
2. Once the file is read in, revert linebreaks:

```r
data <- gsub('<L1nBre@k>', '\n', data, fixed=TRUE)
```

**`\R++(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )` explanation**:

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \R++                     line break sequence (1 or more times, as many
                           as possible), matched possessively
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: R's implementation of regex requires additional backslashes because it ("\") is an escape character in R as well as in regex. Your answr might be useful in other contexts, but not here.

Comment: @IRTFM You misunderstood my intent: the regex string is correct to use in Notepad++. The file needs preprocessing before use in R.

Comment: I was responding to how useful it would be for a person using R. So I think it is you who are misunderstanding the question. If you acknowledge that this addresses a different question, then I think you ought to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

yes, i think regex would be a good way to go

which programming language are you using?

in python format the expression would be something like this:

```
\d{4}-(\d{2}[-: ]){5}(?P<your_data>[\s\S]*?)(?=\s*(\d{4}-(\d{2}[-: ]){5}|$))
```

I have made you an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/2Ax7YQ/1)

**UPDATE:**

if you actually only want to match the lines with timestamps you can simplify the regex-pattern to this:

```
\d{4}-(?:\d{2}[-: ]){5}[^\n]*
```

Comment: thanks, its R studio. and where should i put that regular expression?

Comment: for reg ex in R have a look at: https://databraineo.com/ki-training-resources/r-programmierung/regulaere-ausdruecke-in-r-erklaert/ but from what i read the quantifiers and groupings are supported. Maybe not the "named groups" in "?P<name>" but just use a capturing group and index it

Comment: @EvilSmurf: R's implementation of regex requires additional backslashes because it is an escape character in R as well as in regex. Your answr might be useful in other contexts, but not here.